# El modal aparece y luego se quita

Tags: bootstrap, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo mi app en Laravel 5.1 y me surge el siguiente problema, estoy intentando eliminar un usuario, al pulsar el botón de eliminar me despliega un modal como "advertencia" para saber si quiero eliminar ese usuario y resuelta que cuando pulso el boton de eliminar se me despliega el modal, me muestra el contenido del modal y luego se quita. Aparece como si estuviera activo el modal pero no se ve nada.

Se ve así. 
[image: Modal]

Quiero aclarar que este error me pasa solo cuando al botón de eliminar le envio mediante un `href="{{route('admin.usuario.destroy', $usuario->id) }}"`Si el campo tiene eso se quita el modal, si esta vacio el `href` simplemente aparece el modal.

Aquí es donde tengo mis botones de borrar y editar, que es mi **index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('title','Listado de Usuarios')
@section('contenido')
    @include('alertas.mensajeCreado')
    @include('admin.usuario.modal')

    <!--Metodo para hacer la busqueda en los usuarios-->
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>'admin.usuario.index','method'=>'GET', 'class'=>'navbar-form navbar-left pull-right','role'=>'search'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Buscar'])!!}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>Buscar</button>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
    <!--FIN DEL METODO-->

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <th class="active">Nombre</th>
            <th class="active">Correo</th>
            <th class="active">Tipo de Usuario</th>
            <th class="active">Operacion</th>
        </thead>
        @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
            <tbody>
                <td class="success">{{$usuario->name}}</td>
                <td class="success">{{$usuario->email}}</td>
                <td class="success">{{$usuario->tipoUsuario}}</td>
                <td class="success">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                        <a href="{{route('admin.usuario.edit', $usuario->id) }}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                        <a href="{{route('admin.usuario.destroy', $usuario->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    <div align="center">
        {!! $usuarios->appends(array('search'=> Input::get('search')))->render() !!}

    </div>

@endsection
```

En ese caso si pulso editar, me manda a mi ventana para editar y me carga el usuario que quiero editar, esa sin problema. Mi problema radica principalmente en que al pulsar eliminar se muestra el modal y se quita y queda como se muestra en la imagen. Solo se muestra una vez luego lo pulsas y se pone así.

Mi codigo **modal.blade.php**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">¿Seguro que desea eliminar?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label >Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" disabled>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label >Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" disabled>

                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            {!!Form::open(['route'=>['admin.usuario.destroy'],'method'=>'DELETE'])!!}
            <center>{!!Form::submit('Si',['class'=>'btn btn-danger'])!!}
            <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="return cerrarPopup();">No</a></center>
            {!!Form::close()!!}
            @section('scriptModal')
                {!!Html::script('js/modal.js')!!}
            @endsection
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Modal.js**

```
function cerrarPopup() {
    $("#myModal").modal('toggle');
    $('#myModal').fadeOut();
}
```

Mi metodo destroy dentro del controlador

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);  
    $user->fill($request->all());
}
```

Comment: Puede que solo sea un error al pegar la información aquí, pero no veo el `</div>` que cierra `<div class="modal fade"....>`. Otra cosa que me gustaría saber es si el formulario de borrar que está en el modal funciona, pues no veo que le pases el id del modelo que deseas borrar.

Comment: Si tiene el </div> solo fue error de tipeo al copiar.
No, no recibe nada, no he conseguido que reciba algo ya que igualmente el modal desaparece.

Comment: Aparece algún error en consola?

Comment: Simplemente no me despliega el modal, y sí en el modal llego a poner un {!!Form::open(['route'=>['admin.usuario.destroy',$user],'method'=>'DELETE'])!!} para hacer el borrado, me dice que la variable user no esta definida. Y bueno se la estoy pasando mediante el metodo destroy del controlador

Comment: Bueno, pero según el código que veo $user no estaría definido en ese punto, finalmente es la variable $usuario del foreach la que tiene esa información. En todo caso no hay ningún error en consola cuando intentas mostrar el modal por segunda vez?

Comment: No, no da ningún error en consola, la primera vez lo muestra y se quita y luego se mantiene como esta visto en la imagen.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46029/discussion-between-shaz-and-luis-morales).

Comment: En ocasiones el error puede ser la version de bootstrap que este usando,